# Trouble printing out denominations used in Minimum Change algorithm

Tags: java, dynamic, recursion, dynamic-programming, coin-change

So I wrote a recursive algorithm for the problem of figuring out the least number of 'coins' of a particular set of denominations possible to arrive at a given sum. The algorithm seems to work, but because it's recursive, and calculates every possible option before choosing one or  the other, I'm having a difficult time coming up with a way to print out the denominations used as well. So essentially I can calculate the least number of coins possible to use, but not *which* coins they are. Here's the code and the little main method I'm using to drive it. Any suggestions of streamlining the algorithm itself would also be welcome.

```
public class DynamicCoinChange {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] denoms = {1, 6, 10, 25};
        int numCoins = dynamicCoinChange(denoms, 18, 3);
        System.out.println(numCoins);
    }

    public static int dynamicCoinChange(int[] denoms, int amt, int start) {
        if (amt == 0 || start < 0) {
            return 0;
        } else if (amt == 1) {
            return 1;
        } else if (denoms[start] > amt || 
                dynamicCoinChange(denoms, amt, start-1) < 
                (1 + dynamicCoinChange(denoms, amt-denoms[start], start)) &&
                !(dynamicCoinChange(denoms, amt, start-1) == 0)) {
            return dynamicCoinChange(denoms, amt, start-1);
        } else {
            return 1 + dynamicCoinChange(denoms,amt-denoms[start], start);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to know two pieces of information:

- when a coin is chosen for the optimal solution
- which coin was chosen for the optimal solution

According to your algorithm, we know that we select a coin whenever you return `1`. We also know that the coin chosen at that the index of the coin chosen is `start`. Thus, we have information to solve this problem.

Since performance isn't a problem here, we will simply pass a coins parameter that is filled as the coins are selected.

```
public static int dynamicCoinChange(int[] denoms, int amt, int start, ArrayList<Integer> coins) {
    if (amt == 0 || start < 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (amt == 1) {
        coins.add(1);
        return 1;
    } else if (denoms[start] > amt 
            // Note that these calls are not guaranteed to be in our solution
            // Thus, we make a copy to prevent the calls from modifying our solution
            || dynamicCoinChange(denoms, amt, start-1, new ArrayList<Integer>(coins)) < 
                (1 + dynamicCoinChange(denoms, amt-denoms[start], start, new ArrayList<Integer>(coins))) 
            && !(dynamicCoinChange(denoms, amt, start-1, new ArrayList<Integer>(coins)) == 0)) {
        return dynamicCoinChange(denoms, amt, start-1, coins);
    } else {
        coins.add(denoms[start]);
        return 1 + dynamicCoinChange(denoms,amt-denoms[start], start, coins);
    }
}
```

Since this requires us to change our method signature, we must also modify our driver:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] denoms = {1, 6, 10, 25};
    ArrayList<Integer> coins = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int numCoins = dynamicCoinChange(denoms, 7, 3, coins);
    for (Integer coin : coins)
        System.out.println(coin);
    System.out.println(numCoins);
}
```

At the end of the recursive calls, `coins` should contain the list of coins chosen in chronological order.

Comment: No, this won't work because we're essentially calculating lots of *possible* solutions and then choosing one based on comparison. Yeah, I know it's inefficient haha.

Comment: If you remove the latter half of your second-to-last condition, `|| 
            dynamicCoinChange(denoms, amt, start-1) < 
            (1 + dynamicCoinChange(denoms, amt-denoms[start], start)) &&
            !(dynamicCoinChange(denoms, amt, start-1) == 0)` this should still work fine.

Comment: You mean remove beginning with '||' or beginning with '&&'?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Because then you aren't providing for the possibility that a denomination *less than* the largest is the correct first choice, even though !(denom[start] > amt)

Comment: You are correct. This particular set of coins doesn't allow me to utilize the *greedy choice property*. I modified my solution as a pseudo-tail-call approach. It should be just as inefficient as your current solution if not worse.

Comment: Ah ok, let me look at this. Thanks Gio.

Comment: Regarding optimizations: if you really prefer recursion, you should consider using *continuation passing style*, or specifically, *tail recursion* to reduce the call stack size and the number of backtracking operations. In addition to that, *memoization* can also reduce computation time through caching.

Answer (score 0):

The Minimum Change problem need not be programmed recursively. It can be programmed in a simpler iterative fashion.

```
int[] denoms = { 1, 6, 10, 25 };
int amt = 18;
double[] min = new double[ amt + 1 ];

for( int i = 1; i < min.length; i++ ) { // We're keeping min[ 0 ] as 0/
    min[ i ] = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
}

for( int i = 1; i <= amt; i++ ) {

   for( int j = 0; j <= N - 1; j++ ) {

       if( denoms[ j ] <= i && min[ i - denoms[ j ] ] + 1 < min[ i ] )
           min[ i ] = min[ i - denoms[ j ] ] + 1;

   }
}
```

Here, your solution would be in entry min[amt].

Comment: I know it's inefficient, but I kinda wanted to do this recursively, just because I like recursions haha. :/